# React Native 100% width view in scrollView

Tags: react-native, view, scrollview

I have a horizontal ScrollView

In this ScrollView I want to display multiple **Full height and width** Views.

I don't figure out how to set each View's width to 100%.

Actually it like they have a "auto" width (about 70%)

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView
      style={styles.info}
      horizontal={true}
    >
      {this.state.list.map(item => (
        <View style={styles.item}>...</View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
```

And the styles

```
info: {
 width: "100%",
 height: "100%",
 display: "flex"
},
item: { // props for the items in my views
 display: "flex",
 alignItems: "center",
 justifyContent: "space-between",
 height: "100%",
 paddingTop: 30,
 paddingBottom: 10
}
```

I tried to put `width : "100%"` but of course it didn't work as excepted

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You would have to calculate the width of the device or container.

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

Comment: thanks ! it's seems prety obvious now...^^ i will acecepte the answer

Comment: Glad to help. By the way, this may seem like a hacky way of doing it, but I actually use this method all the time, including in production.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want the dimensions of the device because you'll have to convert the width value of your View you could you the contentContainerStyle props of ScrollView :

```js
<ScrollView
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            flexGrow: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            width: '100%',
          }}
        >

          {history.map((item, index) => (

            <View
              key={index}
              style={{
                height: '10%',
                width: '60%',
                backgroundColor: '#eee',
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
              }}>

              <Text>
                {ToDate(item.timestamp.seconds)[0]}
              </Text>

            </View>
          ))}
</ScrollView>
```

Hope this could help people out here !